# Having issues with watermark in mircosoft word

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, watermark

I'm sending a word document via email, however, I faded the watermark and upon viewing the document in the email, it watermark is still visible. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### Why did you expect the Watermark to be missing or not visible?

- When sending a Word document as an email, you a watermark will not be
  there because it is in the header.
- When sending a Word document via email, the whole document, including
  headers and footers goes along.

Which version of Word are you using?